# Как ограничить количество символов в input number в пределах от 0 до 999.999?

Tags: javascript, css, input

У меня есть input, нужно ограничить вводимое значение от 0 до 999.999.
Пробовал несколько вариантов:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="999.999" step="0.001">

<input type="number" min="0" step="0.001" onkeypress="this.value=this.value.substring(0,4)">
```

Но так ничего и не вышло

Comment: Думаю, без JS не получится ([документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number))

Comment: это не принципиально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути, `max` и `min` это валидаторы. Но они никак не ограничивают ввод с клавиатуры и простой копи-паст.

Воспользуйтесь простым обработчиком события и через JS установите минимальное/максимальное значение при выходе за лимиты.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]');
Array.from(inputs).forEach(input => {
    const min = +input.min;
    const max = +input.max;

    input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        const value = +input.value;
        if (value > max) { input.value = max }
        else if (value < min) { input.value = min }
    }
}));
```

Comment: Мне еще нужно ограничить число до тысячных. К примеру нужно что бы пользователь мог ввести 5.999, 66.111, 110,1. Не подскажите как сделать это?

Comment: можно использовать Math.round на значение. Math.round(value * 1000) / 1000

Comment: Спасибо. Еще бы один моментик подсказали и ситуация будет спасена. Есть ли возможность разделить дробную и целую часть точкой, а не запятой?

Comment: Когда вы вводите вручную, input понимает и `.` и `,` в качестве разделителя. Если пользуетесь `button-controls` для изменения, значение будет выдавать `,`. Если это прям кровь из носу точку надо, то лучше использовать `type="text"` парсить по разделителю `,` типа `input.value = '' + value.split(',').join('.')`. В этом случае, валидаторы `min/max` - это просто болванки, которые работать не будут. Ну и `button-controls` вы не увидите

Comment: я когда ввожу значение через точку - оно обнуляется